# Data validation on ascii input

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to create a program to send messages using ascii decimals, I used try/except for validation but when I test it with letters I get this "✏". why? and is there another way to do the validation all on one line?

```
message=""
letter=9999
while letter!=0:
  try:
    letter=int(input("Please enter a number, if finished enter '0'"))
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid entry, you must enter a number.")
  sub=chr(letter)
  message=message+sub
print("Your secret message is",message,".")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `try-except-else` rather than `try-except` in this case i.e.:

```
message=""
letter=9999
while letter!=0:
  try:
    letter=int(input("Please enter a number, if finished enter '0'"))
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid entry, you must enter a number.")
  else:
    sub=chr(letter)
    message=message+sub
print("Your secret message is",message,".")
```

body of else in `try-except-else` is executed only if error did not occur.